# Who owns taking care of neighbor's lawn creepage?

Tags: poison-ivy

I have two issues in my yard but both are centered around the same question.

If a neighbor has a tree, vines, weeds, whatever - that they are not taking care of and these things are constantly creeping in my yard what can I do about it?

Example #1 - Left side neighbor - Has a 50 foot run of just weeds and vines.  These things can look like a jungle in a couple weeks.  Also there is poison ivy/oak growing inside this.  The neighbors don't care and I am constantly keeping the poison ivy and vines out of my yard.  If I let it go for a few weeks they are attacking my walnut tree about 10 feet from property line.

Example #2 - Back of the yard has a chain link fence.  Not totally sure who owns the fence since it it shared.  But the owner has let thick vines and trees grow in the fence from their side and basically ruined the fence - good 100 foot section.  Again we have issues here with poison ivy and have a hard time keeping it clean because so much of the stuff is starting in neighbor's yard.

Comment: This is completely dependent on your local jurisdiction, please contact them for further information.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is more of a legal question, which depends where you live.  I have the understanding that if something hangs into your yard, you have the right to do with it as you wish (cut it off, leave it).  What neighbors are growing and how it affects you is probably for a judge to decide.

A good solution may be to take a peace offering to your neighbors (beer, a pie, some KFC, whatever) and explain how you see things.  You won't be able to convince then to do proper maintenance, but you will make friends and they may let you take more aggressive action on the problem that exists in their yard (weed killing chemicals, drastic pruning, etc).

You can't make someone care, who doesn't, but you can probaby reach an understanding.

Comment: I am very friendly with neighbors on the left.  It is just an example and huge annoyance.  They like the vines because they cover the electrical wires and they aren't affected by poison ivy.  The ones in the back... Take a lot of beer to figure them out.  They have told me they don't want to see the farmhouse I have in my backyard so they tell their landscaping company not to cut by the fence.  Well 3 years of that and the fence is toast and the first 3 feet on my side gets poison ivy...  Not really looking to sue anyone - just want to know where I am at with things.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bat one eye spraying all of it (even not in my yard) with a mass chemical killer.  If they don't care, I wouldn't care about making the upset.  That's my 2 cents.

Comment: That is pretty much where I am at.  I have a heavy solution I spray but I hate doing it.  And it honestly doesn't kill the vines.  They grow back like weeds.

Comment: Maybe a mechanical solution is best? Dig a trench, add edging board or metal edging or sheet plastic to create a root barrier, then build your own, nicer fence in front of it (or plant a hedge, bamboo, etc.)

Comment: If they are the type of neighbor that is too lazy to take care of their yard, I don't think they will put forth the effort to stop you from doing so.